# How to find the favicon for the New Tab page?

Tags: favicon

Just recently, Chrome seems to have updated and there is now a favicon for the New Tab page. I've been trying to find the new favicon for it, but I've had no luck. Is there any way to find it? Thanks.

[Picture for favicon reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQkPa.png)